# Swift: How to use stderr with Error type?

Tags: swift, command-line-interface, stderr

I am wondering if there is an easy way to use Swift's Error and writing it to the stderr at the same time. For instance, in my CLI application I have this enum for errors:

```swift
enum ErrorList: Error {
    case alreadyInList
}

extension ErrorList: LocalizedError {
    var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {
        case .alreadyInList:
            return NSLocalizedString(
                "This item is already in the list.",
                comment: "Info message")
        }
    }
}
```

Previously I was using a basic `OutputType` enum to write to `stderr`:

`fputs("\u{001B}[0;31m\(message)\n", stderr)`

Is there a way to combine both easily? If I use the above print line with the `ErrorList` enum, I get this error:

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'Int32' to return type 'String?'

How to proceed? Which approach is the best?

Edit: Below I've tried @Sweeper's approach like this:

```swift
func validate() throws {
    guard bla bla else {
        let error = ErrorList.alreadyInList
        fputs("\u{001B}[0;31m\(error.errorDescription)\n", stderr)
        throw error
    }
}

func run() throws {
    try validate()
    bla bla
}
```

Above code gives me double but correct output (in red):

> This item is already in the list.
>
> Error: This item is already in the list.

For below code, I only get

> Error: This item is already in the list.

```swift
func validate() throws {
    guard bla bla else {
        throw = ErrorList.alreadyInList
    }
}

func run() throws {
    do {
        try validate()
        bla bla
    } catch let error as ErrorList {
        fputs("\u{001B}[0;31m\(error.errorDescription)\n", stderr)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how these two are mutually exclusive. Can't you just `fputs` the error after you caught it? `fputs("\u{001B}[0;31m\(error.errorDescription)\n", stderr)`

Comment: @Sweeper, it works, but I cannot use it as `throw fputs("\u{001B}[0;31m\(ErrorList.alreadyInList)\n", stderr)`, for instance with a `guard` statement.

Comment: I would suggest separating your pure Swift code from call site, i.e. let your entry point of the program catch any error that is being thrown by your program (and thus propagated up to this entry point), and in the catch scope you can output the error as a string to `stderror`.

Comment: It seems like you have misunderstood how Swift errors work. On the thrower's side, you just need to do `throw ErrorList.alreadyInList`. You only log the error when you _catch_ the error, in a `do...catch` statement. e.g. `do { try someMethod() } catch let error as ErrorList { fputs(...) } catch { ... }`.

Comment: @Sweeper, thank you! I get it now, was able to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

> but I cannot use it as `throw fputs("\u{001B}[0;31m\(ErrorList.alreadyInList)\n", stderr)`

You just need to separate it into two statements:

```
let error = ErrorList.alreadyInList
fputs("\u{001B}[0;31m\(error.errorDescription)\u{001B}[0m\n", stderr)
throw error
```

You should also consider moving the logging part to the `catch` block of the `do...catch` statement that catches the error. So in your `throws` method, you'd only do:

```
throw ErrorList.alreadyInList
```

and in the caller of the `throws` method, you'd use a `do...catch` statement like so:

```
do {
    try throwsMethod()
} catch let error as ErrorList {
    fputs("\u{001B}[0;31m\(error.errorDescription)\n", stderr)
} catch {
    // handle errors that are not ErrorList
}
```

Seeing your edit, here's what I meant:

First approach:

```
func validate() throws {
    guard bla bla else {
        let error = ErrorList.alreadyInList
        fputs("\u{001B}[0;31m\(error.errorDescription)\n", stderr)
        throw error
    }
}

func run() throws {
    do { 
        try validate()
    } catch {
        // handle the error some other way
        // don't log it again! You already did it!
    }
}
```

Second approach:

```
func validate() throws {
    guard bla bla else {
        throw ErrorList.alreadyInList
    }
}

func run() throws {
    do {
        try validate()
    } catch let error as ErrorList {
        fputs("\u{001B}[0;31m\(error.errorDescription)\n", stderr)
    } catch {
        // handle other errors...
    }
}
```

Comment: It works but there is a glitch: When I do `let error = ErrorList.alreadyInList
fputs("\u{001B}[0;31m\(error.errorDescription)\n", stderr)
throw error`, error message gets printed twice, one without "Error:", and the second one with "Error:". If I only use the second approach with one-line throw statement and the `do`-`catch` block, I don't get the coloured output, apparently it's just the `throw` line. My main function is a `run() throws` function, any reason this is the cause?

Comment: @fankibiber When you were using the first approach, did you just write `try run()` in the _global scope_? The global scope implicitly has a catch statement that logs all the errors that are thrown. You should catch it with an empty `catch` if you don't like this behaviour.

Comment: I updated my main message with the exact code. I run the program in `main.swift`, as `program.main()` you mean that?

Comment: @fankibiber How are you calling `run`?

Comment: I don't call it explicitly, it runs automatically via the argument parser: https://github.com/apple/swift-argument-parser

Comment: @fankibiber That's some crucial information you didn't include! So Swift argument parser will log the errors for you if you don't catch them. This is why you have to catch it in the first approach as well.

Answer (score 1):

Errors are just values. You're free to manipulate them without throwing them. `throws` is just a fancy kind of `return`. It can work with errors generated any way you like.

While Sweeper makes good points, and for a command line app that approach may be best, I often find it better to log at the point of error generation rather than error consumption. I find it makes the logs much more useful by making it much clearer where the original error occurred (I generally log file and line information). Of course, not every kind of error should be logged. But the generator often knows better than the caller in my experience.

So, hoist logging into its own function that takes an Error and returns an Error.

```
func logging(_ error: LocalizedError) -> LocalizedError {
    fputs("\u{001B}[0;31m\(error.errorDescription ?? "")\n", stderr)
    return error
}
```

And now it is clear when you're logging, and you don't need to duplicate the logging code all over the place.

```
func validate() throws {
    guard ... else {
        throw logging(ErrorList.alreadyInList)
    }
}
```

But what if you want to change how logging is done? What about unit testing and all that? Not a problem. In Swift, functions are first class, so you can pass them around, and they can even have defaults.

```
typealias Logger = (LocalizedError) -> LocalizedError

struct Operation {
    let logging: Logger
    init(logging: @escaping Logger = standardLogging) {
        self.logging = logging
    }

    func validate() throws {
        guard false else {
            throw logging(ErrorList.alreadyInList)
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

And now you can create `Operation` with the standard logger trivially, but for unit-testing you could do this:

```
class LogAccumulator {
    var logs: [Error] = []

    func logging(_ error: LocalizedError) -> LocalizedError {
        logs.append(error)
        return error
    }
}

let logs = LogAccumulator()
try? Operation(logging: logs.logging).validate()
print(logs.logs)
```

I have had great success unit testing by validating log output. (I consider the log output to be an explicit part of the interface that should be tested along with other behaviors.) It can let you test all kinds of things that are difficult to check without making private details public.

Comment: While this is a great example, and easy to apply, I'm still getting double output. Most curious, other errors are fine, but the one error I use this function, it's written out twice, one prepended with "Error:" other not.

Comment: @fankibiber The ones prepended with `Error:` are probably from swift argument parser.